# upload an Image to a created folder in Google drive

Tags: c#

I am working in C# .Net and I want to be able to upload an image to a created folder in Google Drive. Please look at the code below. With this code I am able to make the folder and upload image separately, but I want to write a code to upload an image in a created folder

```
Google.Apis.Drive.v2.Data.File body = new Google.Apis.Drive.v2.Data.File();
body.Title = "My first folder";
body.Description = "document description";
body.MimeType = "application/vnd.google-apps.folder";

// service is an authorized Drive API service instance
Google.Apis.Drive.v2.Data.File file = service.Files.Insert(body).Fetch();

Google.Apis.Drive.v2.Data.File body1 = new Google.Apis.Drive.v2.Data.File();
body1.Title = "My first folder";
body1.MimeType = "image/jpeg";

//------------------------------------------

byte[] byteArray = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes("Bluehills.jpg");
System.IO.MemoryStream stream = new System.IO.MemoryStream(byteArray);

FilesResource.InsertMediaUpload request = service.Files.Insert(body, stream, "image/jpeg");
request.Upload();

Google.Apis.Drive.v2.Data.File file1 = request.ResponseBody;
Console.WriteLine("File id: " + file1.Id);
Console.WriteLine("Press Enter to end this process.");
Console.ReadLine();
```

Answer (score 3):

> To insert a file in a particular folder, specify the correct ID in the parents property of the file

https://developers.google.com/drive/folder

so use `file.Id` as parent of `body`

**edit** quite hard to see which is the folder and which the file because of `file` and `file1` and `body` and `body1` but I believe it is the file1.id which should be the parent of body1

**edit 2**

```
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(file1.id)) {
    body1.Parents = new List<ParentReference>()
       { new ParentReference() {Id = file1.id} };
}
```

**edit 3**
full code:

```
Google.Apis.Drive.v2.Data.File folder = new Google.Apis.Drive.v2.Data.File();
folder.Title = "My first folder";
folder.Description = "folder document description";
folder.MimeType = "application/vnd.google-apps.folder";

// service is an authorized Drive API service instance
Google.Apis.Drive.v2.Data.File file = service.Files.Insert(folder).Fetch();

Google.Apis.Drive.v2.Data.File theImage = new Google.Apis.Drive.v2.Data.File();
theImage.Title = "My first image";
theImage.MimeType = "image/jpeg";
theImage.Parents = new List<ParentReference>()
   { new ParentReference() {Id = file.Id} };

byte[] byteArray = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes("Bluehills.jpg");
System.IO.MemoryStream stream = new System.IO.MemoryStream(byteArray);

FilesResource.InsertMediaUpload request = service.Files.Insert(theImage, stream, "image/jpeg");
request.Upload();

Google.Apis.Drive.v2.Data.File imageFile = request.ResponseBody;
Console.WriteLine("File id: " + imageFile.Id);
Console.WriteLine("Press Enter to end this process.");
Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: Thanks for reply JP by running this code i am getting an error'Google.Apis.Drive.v2.Data.File' does not contain a definition for 'id' and no extension method 'id' accepting a first argument of type 'Google.Apis.Drive.v2.Data.File' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Thanks JP actually there is a minor change theImage.Parents = new List<ParentReference>()
   { new ParentReference() {Id = file.Id} }; after doing the change we are getting the output thanks so much

Comment: One more question i want to iterate folder from my Google-drive account and i want to use OAUTH method only,as i am new for Google- drive pls help me waiting for the reply